# How to change hand tool shortcut in Photoshop

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-photoshop, shortcuts, photoshop-cs6

I have been wondering if I can change the key binding to trigger the hand tool (default: <kbd>Space</kbd>).

I know how to change the shortcut to activate it (default <kbd>H</kbd>) but I don't want to change this. I want the... let's call it quick select hand tool... thing! xD

Is it possible?